# How to assign new value array to old array inside method?

Tags: javascript, arrays, filter, slice

There are a lot of mine methods with standard `filter`, `map` and so on to return a new array.

```
let array = [1, 2, 3, 4];
array = someFilter(array);
array = otherFilter(array);
array = someMap(array);
```

How can I do it without return new array?

```
let array = [1, 2, 3, 4];
someFilter(array);
otherFilter(array);
someMap(array);
```

For example

```
let x = [1, 2, 3, 4];
filter(x);
// x still 1, 2, 3, 4

function filter(array){
    let newArray = array.filter((item) => item % 2 == 0);
    array = newArray; // what do here?
}
```

## Update

There is my solution

```
function replace(oldArray, newArray){
    oldArray.length = 0;
    push(oldArray, newArray);
}

function push(sourceArray, ...additionalArray) {
    additionalArray.forEach((array) => {
        if (array.length < 1000){
            sourceArray.push.apply(sourceArray, array);
        } else {
            array.forEach((item) => sourceArray.push(item));
        }
    });
    return sourceArray;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`Array.splice()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) to remove all items from the original array, and add the items from the new array:

```js
function filter(array) {
  const newArray = array.filter((item) => item % 2 == 0);
  array.splice(0, array.length, ...newArray);
}

const x = [1, 2, 3, 4];

filter(x);

console.log(x)
```

You also set the array's length to be 0 to remove all items, and then push the new items:

```js
function filter(array) {
  const newArray = array.filter((item) => item % 2 == 0);
  array.length = 0;
  array.push(...newArray);
}

const x = [1, 2, 3, 4];

filter(x);

console.log(x)
```

Comment: Will it work with difficult items? For example, `[ { key: { name: { first: 'first', last: 'last' } } }, ... ]`

Comment: This ways mutate the original array, non-primitive items are not cloned - the reference to the item is copied from one array to another.

Comment: Yes, it enough `the reference to the item is moved from one array to another`. I was confused that the elements are being removed.

Comment: If an `array` has a lot of items (1000, 5000), is there a problem with the `...newArray` operation?

Comment: The spread operator is not stack safe, which means that it can cause a stack overflow, if there are too many items. I've used spread with arrays of about 70-80Ks with no problem. If you are going to work arrays of this size, I suggest using the 2nd solution, avoiding spread, and pushing the items with a simple loop.